# Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource - using spring-core.4_2_5

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to deploy my REST service using Tomcat 6 and getting the above mentioned error while trying to start tomcat. This app runs fine in Jetty.

All research has pointed to a missing spring-core jar file in my WAR file, but it is already there as far as I can tell.

Any ideas what could be missing/no configured correctly? We are using Java 7.

Here is a bit more of my console output. Please let me know if I can provide any other info to help figure out the problem.

```
15:52:31.713 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'cxf.config0'
15:52:31.713 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'loggingInInterceptor'
15:52:31.713 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'loggingOutInterceptor'
15:52:31.713 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'dynamicPropertyUtil'
15:52:31.713 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'dynamicPropertyUtil'
15:52:31.714 [main] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamicPropertyUtil' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource
15:52:31.714 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@360c65bd: defining beans [cxf,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor,productQualificationSOAP,cxf.config0,abstractLoggingInterceptor,loggingInInterceptor,loggingOutInterceptor,dynamicPropertyUtil,cgsProductQualificationGatewayHandler,filterLoopQualForEOSRulesHandler,productSpecsToGenericServiceTypeMapper,template,consumerTemplate,cgsProductQualificationSvcsCamelContext:beanPostProcessor,cgsProductQualificationSvcsCamelContext]; root of factory hierarchy
15:52:31.714 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy method 'shutdown' on bean with name 'cxf'
15:52:31.748 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamicPropertyUtil' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

and a bit lower in the same exception...

```
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.Resource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

[The WEB-INF\lib of my WAR file...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqvfg.png)

[Dependency hierarchy in my POM.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXK7H.png)

**UPDATE: Here is my applicationContext.xml and pom.xml. I removed as much of the seemingly irrelevant code as I thought possible to make it not so huge..**

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
    xmlns:cxfbus="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/core 
       http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <!-- <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/cxfClientContext.xml" /> -->


    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="productQualificationSOAP" address="/ProductQualification"
        endpointName="s:ProductQualificationSoap" serviceName="s:ProductQualification"
        serviceClass="com.mycompany.cgs.marketingoffermanagement.productqualification.ProductQualificationSoapImpl"
        wsdlURL="META-INF/wsdl/productQualification/ProductQualification.wsdl"
        xmlns:s="http://cgs.mycompany.com/MarketingOfferManagement/ProductQualification">
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
    <cxfbus:bus>
        <cxfbus:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
        </cxfbus:inInterceptors>
        <cxfbus:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor" />
        </cxfbus:outInterceptors>
        <cxfbus:outFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor" />
        </cxfbus:outFaultInterceptors>
        <cxfbus:inFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
        </cxfbus:inFaultInterceptors>
    </cxfbus:bus>

    <bean id="abstractLoggingInterceptor" abstract="true">
        <property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="loggingInInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"
        parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor" />
    <bean id="loggingOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"
        parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor" />

    <bean id="dynamicPropertyUtil"
        class="com.myco.cgs.productorder.services.productQualification.util.DynamicPropertyUtil" />

    <bean id="cgsProductQualificationGatewayHandler"
        class="com.myco.cgs.productorder.services.productQualification.CGSProductQualificationGatewayHandler" />
    <bean id="filterLoopQualForEOSRulesHandler"
        class="com.myco.cgs.productorder.services.filterLoopQual.FilterLoopQualForEOSRulesHandler" />
    <bean id="productSpecsToGenericServiceTypeMapper"
        class="com.myco.cgs.services.dataaccess.productspec.mapper.ProductSpecToUnderlyingMapper" />

    <camelContext id="cgsProductQualificationSvcsCamelContext"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <packageScan>
            <package>com.myco.cgs.productorder.services.productQualification.camel.route</package>
        </packageScan>
    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xxx.xxx.xx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>productQualification</artifactId>
    <name>Project Name</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <description>My Web Service</description>
    <url>http://www.url.com</url>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <camel.version>2.17.1</camel.version>
        <cxf.version>3.1.6</cxf.version>
        <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.6</slf4j.version>
        <api-java.MiddlewareUtils.version>15.1.0.1</api-java.MiddlewareUtils.version>
        <api-java.ensemble-api.version>16.1.0.1</api-java.ensemble-api.version>
        <!-- <api-java.MiddlewareUtils.version>15.1.0.1</api-java.MiddlewareUtils.version> -->
    </properties>

    ...

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Jolt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jolt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <!--<scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/build/jolt.jar</systemPath> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joltjse</groupId>
            <artifactId>joltjse</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <!--<scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/build/joltjse.jar</systemPath> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joltwls</groupId>
            <artifactId>joltwls</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <!--<scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/build/joltwls.jar</systemPath> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Camel Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Axis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0ctl</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- RPC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <!-- <groupId>javax.xml.rpc</groupId> -->
            <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>api-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>MiddlewareUtils</artifactId>
            <version>${api-java.MiddlewareUtils.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>api-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>ensemble-api</artifactId>
            <version>${api-java.ensemble-api.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>neethi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.cgs</groupId>
            <artifactId>dataAccess</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joltjse</groupId>
            <artifactId>joltjse</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <!--<scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/build/joltjse.jar</systemPath> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>orai18n</groupId>
            <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    ...

        <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>underlyingServices/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar</packagingExcludes>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>

                    <execution>
                        <id>Product Qualification Service WSDL2JAVA</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/wsdl/productQualification/ProductQualification.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-autoNameResolution</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-xjc-Xannotate</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                    <bindingFiles>
                                        <bindingFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/xsd/bindings/GlobalProductQualificationBindings.xjb</bindingFile>
                                    </bindingFiles>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <!-- plugin so you can run mvn jetty:run -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>com.sun.management.jmxremote</name>
                            <value />
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <stopPort>8091</stopPort>
                    <stopKey>stopItYou</stopKey>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    <jvmArgs>-Xms128M -Xmx512M -XX:PermSize=16M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M</jvmArgs>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: can you please post your applicationContext.xml

Comment: Can you please also paste your pom.xml?

Comment: Please see the update in my post. Sorry for the delay... I'm new to actually posting on stackoverflow, so I was expecting an email if anybody responded... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue is resolved, although I'm not quite sure how. I added the spring-core dependency to my pom directly, instead of pulling it in though camel-spring. I also used version 4.2.6 instead of 4.2.5. Once I did this, the issue was resolved and tomcat started just fine. Wew!

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```